Dividing $N$ coins into at most $K$ groups such that I can get any number of coins by selecting whole groups
Problem
Inspired from Dividing $100$ coins into $7$ groups such that I can choose any number of coins by selecting whole groups . I am interested in the number of possible ways we can get such a split.
The formal problem statement is: Count the number of multisets $S$ containing positive integers, and of size at most $K$, where for all $x \in \mathbb{N}, x\le N$, we can get a subset $A \subseteq S$ such that $\sum_{s\in A} s = x$.
Example: for $N=10, K=5$, we can get $8$ such multisets:
[3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[4, 3, 1, 1, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 2, 1, 1, 1]
[5, 2, 2, 1]
[5, 3, 1, 1]


What I've achieved
For any such multiset $S$, let's label the largest integer as $s_0$. Then we can deduce three things:

$s_0 \le \left\lceil \frac{N}{2} \right\rceil$

Proved by contradiction: If $s_0 >  \left\lceil \frac{N}{2} \right\rceil$, then we cannot get any subset $A \subseteq S$  which contains exactly $\left\lceil \frac{N}{2} \right\rceil$ coins.


$S \setminus \{s_0\}$ should necessarily hold the same property for $N-s_0$ coins and $K-1$ groups, i.e., for all $x \in \mathbb{N}, x\le N-s_0$, we can get a subset $A\in S \setminus \{s_0\}$ such that $\sum_{s\in A} s = x$

Proved by contradiction: take the smallest $x_0$ which doesn't hold this property for $S \setminus \{s_0\}$. Note that $x_0 < s_0$, because if $x_0 \ge s_0$, then there must exist an element $s_1 > x_0 \ge s_0$ inside $S \setminus \{s_0\}$, failing the assumption that $s_0$ is largest. Then as we now know $x_0 < s_0$, we deduce $x_0$ doesn't satisfy the property for $S$ with $N$ coins too, as any subset $A \subseteq S$  which contains $s_0$ will have a sum $\ge s_0> x_0$.


The above two points are sufficient to show that $S$ satisfies the property too.

By construction



By the above three properties, we can create a recursion for the number of multisets. Let the number of multisets where all integers $\le s_0$ be defined as $f(N, K, s_0)$, then $$f(N, K, s_0) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } N=0 \land K\ge 0 \\
0 & \text{ if } N>0 \land K=0 \\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\min\left(\left\lceil \frac{N}{2} \right\rceil, s_0\right)} f(N-i, K-1, i) & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
Here we can get the answer to the original problem by calling $f(N, K, N)$. Python code for the same:
import time

start_time = time.process_time()

def countWays(n, k, prev, v):
    if n == 0:
        return [v.copy()]
    if k == 0:
        return []

    sm = []
    for x in range(1, min(prev, (n+1)//2)+1):
        v.append(x)
        sm = sm + countWays(n-x, k-1, x, v)
        v.pop()
    return sm

N = 10
K = 5
a = countWays(N, K, N, [])
print(len(a))
for b in a:
    print(b)
                

print(N, K, time.process_time() - start_time)

Next steps
I am looking for a closed form formula, or a polynomial (w.r.t. $N$) time algo for the above. This might be too close to the partition problem for it to be solved in polynomial time, but I am not sure how to verify that. If this is too diffixult, I will accept special cases of $K=N$ or $K = \lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor +1$ as well.
